# How to show Tor nodes or exits

Tags: configuration

When I used Tor a time ago, on the left top corner I could see wich nodes and exit was currently used.

Now I don't find that function anymore.

How do I do this?

Thanks in advance for any reaction!

Answer (score 1):

This is from the [Tor Browser manual](https://tb-manual.torproject.org/managing-identities/) on the Tor website:

> THE URL BAR
>
> Tor Browser centers your web experience around your relationship with
>   the website in the URL bar. Even if you connect to two different sites
>   that use the same third-party tracking service, Tor Browser will force
>   the content to be served over two different Tor circuits, so the
>   tracker will not know that both connections originate from your
>   browser.
>
> On the other hand, all connections to a single website address will be
>   made over the same Tor circuit, meaning you can browse different pages
>   of a single website in separate tabs or windows, without any loss of
>   functionality.
>   [image]
>
> You can see a diagram of the circuit that Tor Browser is using for the
>   current tab in the site information menu, in the URL bar.
>
> In the circuit, the Guard or entry node is the first node and it's
>   automatically and randomly selected by Tor. But it is different from
>   the other nodes in the circuit. In order to avoid profiling attacks,
>   the Guard node changes only after 2-3 months, unlike the other nodes,
>   which change with every new domain. For more information about Guards,
>   consult the FAQ and Support Portal.